# XSLT parsing: How to select namespace's value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABCD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="3.0" >
   <XYZ>
      <Type>HAS_STATE</Type>
      <Target xsi:type="ns:State">
        <MNOP>Hello</MNOP>
      </Target>
   </XYZ>
</ABCD>
```

I need to extract the value of Target element i.e. "ns:State", but unable to do it. Can you please help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve]? State your current stylesheet and expected result. "ns:State" is the value of an attribute of element `Target`.

Comment: Hi @uL1, thanks a ton! You have solved the problem! I created a xsi namespace and extracted the value using `Target/@xsi:type`.
I was parsing this as an element and not an attribute, and that's the real mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> need to extract the value of Target element i.e. "ns:State"

**Correct:** "ns:State" is the value of an attribute of element `Target`.

**XPath** `/ABCD/XYZ/Target/@xsi:type`.

Attributes needs `@`. As long the namespace-prefix is given, just write it down.